# Using scipy kmeans for cluster analysis

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, cluster-analysis, k-means

I want to understand [`scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans.html#scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans).

Having a number of points distributed in 2D space, the problem is to group them into clusters. This problem came to my attention reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44658086/finding-circles-in-scatter) and I was thinking that `scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans` would be way to go.

This is the data:
[image]

Using the following code, the aim would be to get the center point of each of the 25 clusters.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.cluster.vq import vq, kmeans, whiten

pos = np.arange(0,20,4)
scale = 0.4
size = 50
x = np.array([np.random.normal(i,scale,size*len(pos)) for i in pos]).flatten()
y = np.array([np.array([np.random.normal(i,scale,size) for i in pos]) for j in pos]).flatten()


plt.scatter(x,y, s=16, alpha=0.4)


#perform clustering with scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans
features = np.c_[x,y]

# take raw data to cluster
clusters = kmeans(features,25)
p = clusters[0]
plt.scatter(p[:,0],p[:,1], s=81, c="crimson")

# perform whitening (normalization to std) first
whitened = whiten(features) 
clustersw = kmeans(whitened,25)
q = clustersw[0]*features.std(axis=0)
plt.scatter(q[:,0],q[:,1], s=25, c="gold")

plt.show()
```

The result looks like this:
[image]

The red dots mark the location of the cluster centers without whitening, the yellow points those with whitening being used. While they are different, the main problem is that they are obviously not all at the correct position. Because the clusters are all well separated, I'm having trouble to understand why this simple clustering fails.

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25301466/trouble-with-scipy-kmeans-and-kmeans2-clustering-in-python) which reports about `kmeans` not giving accurate results, but the answer is not really statisfactory. The suggested solution to use `kmeans2` with `minit='points'` did not work either; i.e. `kmeans2(features,25, minit='points')` gives a similar result as the above.

So the question would be, is there a way to perform this easy clustering problem with `scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans`? And if so, how would I make sure to get the correct result.

Comment: I was just doing the same thing (inspired by the same question).  I got more reliable results by using a large value for the `iter` argument of `kmeans`, going as high as `iter=800`.  And yes, that makes it slow.

Comment: Really? Using `iter=800` I get the same roughly; [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqKmp.png).

Comment: My clusters had a high variance than yours.  When I tightened up the clusters, I had to crank up `iter` even more.  I just ran an example where `iter=2000` was not enough, but `iter=10000` found the expected centers.  (I'm not saying this is a great solution to the problem; I'm just exploring what it takes to get `kmeans` to work.)

Comment: Ok, so for the example above using iter=4000 does it. Feel free to provide that as an answer if you like. Of course it would be more interesting to know the logic behind setting iter to 10, 50 or 10000 but I think it still answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

On data like this, whitening does not make a difference: your x and y axes were already similarly scaled.

K-means does not reliably find the global optimum. It tends to get stuck in local optima. That is why it is common to use multiple runs and keep the best fit only, and to experiment with complex initialization procedures like k-means++.

Comment: Can you detail what you mean by "complex initialization procedures like k-means++"?

Comment: Google for k-means++

Comment: Ok, sorry, what I mean is given the problem from the question, what would be the way to implement k-means++? Is there a scipy function to do it? Would I need to change to scikit-learn or some other library? Would the answer to the question thus be that it is not possible with scipy tools alone?

Comment: You need to **understand the problem**, not just find a function/option that sometimes is a bit better, sometimes not.